# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void' in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on angular project.
I'm getting error - Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'
Here is what I done so far -
.ts file -

```
getDoctorDetails(){
    this.algoliaService.getDoctorDetails()
    .then(({ hits }) => {
          this.doctorDetails = hits[0]; 
    });
}
```

service.ts file -

```
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  environment.algolia_application_id,
  environment.algolia_search_api_key
);

export class AlgoliaService {
    doctorsConfig = {
        indexName: 'doctor',
        searchClient
    };
    getDoctorDetails() {
      const index = searchClient.initIndex(this.doctorsConfig.indexName);
      return index.search('', {
            hitsPerPage: 1,
        })
    }
}
```

How to solve error? - Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void' in angular
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, obviously `this.algoliaService.getDoctorDetails()` returns `void` so maybe start looking what `index.search('', {
            hitsPerPage: 1,
        })` returns? You could help yourself (if you're already using TypeScript) by declaring the return types as well, that would make the problem obvious.

Comment: Where do you get this error? Note that in the first code block you are not returning anything, so that method will implicitly produce `void`. If you're trying to call `getDoctorDetails().then()` (referring to the `getDoctorDetails` shown in the first block) TypeScript is correct with the compilation error. IF it's about `getDoctorDetails().then()` that targets the method from the second code block, that suggests that `index.search()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @smutje It returns json object and I getting that object in componet file but getting this error.

Comment: Where are you getting that object? You haven't included that part.

Comment: @Smutje Getting that object in component file in then block.

Comment: I only see 1 `then` and you mentioned that this `then` is a compile error, so what `then` block are you talking about now?!

Comment: @Smutje I have used then block only in component file.

Comment: @VLAZ When I don't use {  hitsPerPage: 1 } this part the don't get any error.